# How to remote terminal into the standard desktop?

Tags: xfce, remote-desktop, xrdp

I want to remote terminal into the Ubuntu desktop 14.x from Windows.  To that end I installed xrdp (via `apt-get install xrdp`) and enabled Sharing via Desktop Sharing Preferences and I am able to connect.

But that takes me to the Xfce desktop. I want to remote into the regular desktop.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, it's not possible to use xrdp to connect to the standard desktop (unity).  To work with xrdp and Ubuntu 12.10 and later, you need to specify an alternate desktop (xfce, mate-desktop,...)

if this would fit your needs, you could configure your Ubuntu system to have vnc configured to run at startup and use xrdp to connect to the standard Ubuntu desktop.  in the xrdp login box, you will need to select the console option

A full instruction guide can be found [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5956)